# Sed -i is creating new lines and printing output

Tags: python, shell, sed

We have a script which compares two CSV files rows and printing “match found” or 
“not found” output at the end of the 2nd file for each row. It was working really good, but recently I have updated Cygwin, not sure what went wrong, now it prints the output to the next line for all rows. Something has changed with new version of Cygwin- Python, and shell

Below is the code line I am using:

```
sed -i "${lineNum}s/$/,Found/" file2.csv

File1.csv
abcd efgh ijkl
mnop qrst xyz

File2.csv
abcd efgh ijkl      found
mnop qrst xyzzz     not found
```

it should print as above. but it is displaying as below.

```
File2.csv
abcd efgh  ijkl
     found
mnop qrst     xyzzz    
     not found
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to work from -- without actually seeing examples of what the data should be and what it is, it's not clear "prints the output to the next line" actually means in practice. Please [edit] to provide an example (ideally, the smallest possible example) of input for which the process misbehaves; an exact command for the modification; your expected output; and your actual output. See the Help Center guide on building a [mcve].

Comment: BTW, if this is really doing a line-by-line comparison, using `sed -i` is probably not a great idea -- every time you run that command it's rewriting the entire output file from scratch. Much more efficient to generate an output file from your two inputs in just one pass using an algorithm akin to that implemented by `comm`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I edited the question. Could you please look into it again.

Comment: Thank you -- that's not really a [mcve], since it doesn't provide (the shortest possible) code someone can use to get from the input to the actual output, but it's probably good enough.

Comment: BTW, consider including output from `cat -A File2.csv` in your question, particularly if my current guess is wrong.

Comment: Thank You very much for all your time Charles.. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an issue with newlines. Windows platforms use `\r\n` as a newline sequence, whereas UNIX platforms use `\n` alone. If your file contains `\r\n` and your code is inserting content after the `\r` and before the `\n`, that's likely to be implicated.

An easy fix is to convert your files to UNIX format first, and (optionally) back when you're done:

```
dos2unix file2.csv
sed -i "${lineNum}s/$/,Found/" file2.csv
unix2dos file2.csv ## if you want DOS-style newlines
```

Comment: Great... Worked.. Thank You very much!!